# Passing a JSON object through the Navigator in React Native

Tags: json, react-native

I'm trying to minimize the amount of REST calls in my app by using the data once received all over the app. I can successfully pass each of the properties in the `JSON` file as props, but what I want is to send the whole object at once.

Following is the code I'm using to push the the page and the props.

```
itemClicked: function (id, name, description, item) {
    this.props.navigator.push({
        title: "View Page",
        component: ViewPage,
        passProps: { id: id, name: name, description: description, item: item },
    });
}
```

The passed props id, name and description works perfectly. But item (The object) doesn't seem to function like a normal `JSON` object. But if you print the whole object itself, it'll print the all of the content. Still, you can't access each of those individually.

How to do this properly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you're getting a stringified JSON object? Try `JSON.parse(item)`

Comment: @thameera Thank you. That worked.